# Typesafe unknown return type in recursive function?

Tags: java, generics, recursion, unchecked

I have a recursive method to flatten nested maps, within a `Stream`. It returns object, since I don't know in advance about the depth of nesting:

```
static Stream<Object> nestedMapFlattener(Object o) {
    if (o instanceof Map<?, ?>) {
        return
                ((Map<?, ?>) o)
                        .entrySet()
                        .stream()
                        .flatMap(entry ->
                                nestedMapFlattener(entry.getValue())
                                        .map(entryOrSingle -> new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(entry.getKey(), entryOrSingle))
                        )
                ;
    }
    return Stream.of(o);
}
```

To use it I cast within the stream, of course getting an unchecked warning:

```
@Test
public void nestedMapFlattenerTest() {
    Map<Integer, Map<Integer, Map<Integer, Integer>>> threeFoldNestMap = new HashMap<Integer, Map<Integer, Map<Integer, Integer>>>() {{
        put(
                1,
                new HashMap<Integer, Map<Integer, Integer>>() {{
                    put(
                            11,
                            new HashMap<Integer, Integer>() {{
                                put(111, 1110);
                                put(112, 1120);
                            }}
                    );
                    put(
                            12,
                            new HashMap<Integer, Integer>() {{
                                put(121, 1210);
                                put(122, 1220);
                            }}
                    );
                }}
        );
        put(
                2,
                new HashMap<Integer, Map<Integer, Integer>>() {{
                    put(
                            21,
                            new HashMap<Integer, Integer>() {{
                                put(211, 2110);
                                put(212, 2120);
                            }}
                    );
                    put(
                            22,
                            new HashMap<Integer, Integer>() {{
                                put(221, 2210);
                                put(222, 2220);
                            }}
                    );
                }}
        );
        put(
                3,
                new HashMap<Integer, Map<Integer, Integer>>() {{
                    put(
                            31,
                            new HashMap<Integer, Integer>() {{
                                put(311, 3110);
                                put(312, 3120);
                            }}
                    );
                    put(
                            32,
                            new HashMap<Integer, Integer>() {{
                                put(321, 3210);
                                put(322, 3220);
                            }}
                    );
                }}
        );

    }};


     nestedMapFlattener(threeFoldNestMap)
        .map(o -> (Map.Entry<Integer, Map.Entry<Integer, Map.Entry<Integer, Integer>>>) o)
        .map(o -> "" + o.getKey() + " " + o.getValue().getKey() + " " + o.getValue().getValue().getKey() + " " + o.getValue().getValue().getValue())
        .forEach(System.out::println);
    //prints:
    //1 11 112 1120
    //1 11 111 1110
    //1 12 121 1210
    //1 12 122 1220
    //2 21 211 2110
    //2 21 212 2120
    //2 22 221 2210
    //2 22 222 2220
    //3 32 321 3210
    //3 32 322 3220
    //3 31 311 3110
    //3 31 312 3120
}
```

I was wondering, if there is a better way to do this, since I think it kind of abuses the the idea of typesafety?

Comment: so `nestedMapFlattener` returns a stream of `Intger` right?

Comment: It depends. In the test case it returns `Map.Entry<Integer, Map.Entry<Integer, Map.Entry<Integer, Integer>>>`. But if you cal it with just a `List` of integers, it will return `Stream<Integer>`.